# React - Setting state of object based on user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an API which returns an object which I store in my component state as `'content'`. I use this state to pre-populate a page of input fields. The user can make changes to these inputs which in turn alters my state. Submitting the form simply passes this new content object to a save API which in turn saves the changes.

A simple function listens for input onChange events and then alters my state based on the name of the input (taken from Cory House's React tutorial on Pluralsight):

```
updateContentState = (e) => {
  const field = e.target.name;
  const content = Object.assign({}, this.state.content);
  content[field] = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ content });
}

<ManageContentForm
  onChange={this.updateContentState}
  content={this.state.content}
/>
```

I would call this function in my ManageContentForm component like so:

```
<TextInput
  name="title"
  label="Title"
  value={content.title}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

This works great for top level key/value pairs, but I have a `main_content` key which includes an array of objects. Whereas the top level key/values are always present, the data inside of main_content is freeform (users can click a button to add a new title, paragraph, accordion, bullet point etc) so sometimes this will be empty and other times it will have a load of objects in it. Here is an example of my JSON.

```
title: '',
summary: '',
main_content: [
  {
    data: 'Notes',
    type: 'heading',
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        detail: '',
        title: '',
      },
    ],
    type: 'accordion',
  },
],
```

Say I had a text input which was for altering the value in the 'detail' key, the same approach as what works for top-level key/value pairs doesn't work...

```
<TextInput
  name="main_content[1].data.title"
  label="Accordian Title"
  value={content.main_content[1].data.title}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Might be worth noting that I am using `.map` to loop through the objects in `main_content` so I do have access to the index of each particular object.

Answer (score -1):

- write a method to insert/update the appropriate piece of data into main content directly
- consider breaking up "main content" if needed, to make it more accessible

Comment: If possible can you please elaborate on this answer and provide some code examples?